# installing spyder on anaconda virtual environment: stick at solving environment

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I made a virtual environment called Python3613 (an older version of Python) to do some homework. Homework sadly only can work in this version. I tried to install Spyder on this environment, but it is stuck at the following:

(Python3613) C:\Users\ikim1>conda install spyder
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \

I have tried the code :
(Python3613) C:\Users\ikim1>conda config --set channel_priority strict

But I think i should specify channel priority is for the virtual environment.
anyways, How can I solve this stuck issue?

Comment: While I am not positive, I believe the issue maybe that you are attempting to install the latest version of Spyder(5.1+)  in the Python 3.6 environment.  My experience is that you need to install an earlier version such as Spyder ver 4+.  To do this, go to the home page of the environment in Navigator, select the gear in upper right corner of the Spyder Panle and select something like Spyder 4.2.5 and install.

Comment: Hey Sorry it took a while to get back. I ended up using mamba. Apparently, mamba pruning is much better than conda.